# UIView Orientation change programmatically

Tags: iphone, uiview

i have uiview with a uiviewtablecontroller added as subview, my device starts in landscape mode but tableviewcontroller is always in the portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

The below method "return yes" will make orientation change if it is "return NO" the orientation will not change.Use this method in your view.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation 
{

return YES;

}
```

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

My sandbox app:
https://github.com/comonitos/programatical_device_orientation

in interface (h file) :

```
    BOOL rotated;
```

in implementation (m file):

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    return rotated;
    }
    -(void) setup 
    {
    rotated = YES;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    rotated = NO;
    }
```